# Parsing scala Json into dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Sample Json

```
 "alternateId": [
    {
        "type": "POPID",
        "value": "1-7842-0759-001"
    },
    {
        "type": "CAMID",
        "value": "CAMID 0000-0002-7EC1-02FF-O-0000-0000-2"
    },
    {
        "type": "ProgrammeUuid",
        "value": "1ddb01e2-6146-4e10-bba9-dde40d0ad886"
    }
]
```

I want to update a existing dataframe with two columns, those two columns are POPID and CAMID . These two values  needs to be parsed from json structure 
I dont know how to parse this structure , Can you help me on what do i need to change on fetchField method. As per above json POPID is placed first and CAMID is placed second, but in real jsons, it can be placed at one of those 3 places inside alternateId.

```
 val fetchCAMID_udf = udf(fetchCAMID _)
 val fetchPOPID_udf = udf(fetchPOPID _)

 var updatedDf = //Data frame initialize

 updatedDf = updatedDf.withColumn("CAMID", fetchCAMID_udf(col("alternate_id")))
 updatedDf = updatedDf.withColumn("POPID", fetchPOPID_udf(col("alternate_id")))
 updatedDf .show(10,false)


 def fetchCAMID(jsonStr: String): String = {
var CAMID: String = fetchField(jsonStr, "CAMID")
 CAMID
}

 def fetchPOPID(jsonStr: String): String = {
fetchField(jsonStr, "POPID")
}


 def fetchField(jsonStr: String, fieldName: String): String = {
 try {
   implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
   val extractedField = jsonStr match {
    case "(unknown)" => jsonStr
    case _ => {
      val json = JsonMethods.parse(jsonStr)
      val resultExtracted = (json \\ fieldName)
      val result = resultExtracted match {
        case _: JString => resultExtracted.extract[String]
        case _: JInt => resultExtracted.extract[Int].toString
        case _: JObject => "(unknown)"
      }
      result
    }
   }
  extractedField
 }
catch{
  case e: Exception =>{
    log.error(s"Fetch field failed. Field name: $fieldName . Json: $jsonStr")
    "(unknown)"
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `fetchField` function as the following

```
def fetchField(jsonStr: String, fieldName: String): String = {
  try {
    val typeAndValue = (JsonMethods.parse("{"+jsonStr+"}") \ "alternateId" \ "type" \\ classOf[JString]).zip(JsonMethods.parse("{"+jsonStr+"}") \ "alternateId" \ "value" \\ classOf[JString])
    typeAndValue.filter(_._1 == fieldName).map(_._2).toList(0)
  }catch{
    case e: Exception =>{
      "(unknown)"
    }
  }
}
```

and you get the `CAMID` and `POPID` populated

Answer (score 0):

you can read the JSON using Spark and get it using regular spark operations

```
val df=spark.read.option("multiLine",true).json("test.json")

 df.select($"alternateId".getItem(0).as("pop"),$"alternateId".getItem(1).as("cam")).select($"pop.value".as("POPID"),$"cam.value".as("CAMID")).show()

+---------------+--------------------+
|          POPID|               CAMID|
+---------------+--------------------+
|1-7842-0759-001|CAMID 0000-0002-7...|
+---------------+--------------------+
```