# Convert entry hocon to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hocon

I have this entry "channels" in hocon format:

```
param {
  channels = [
    {
      name = "MainPhone"
      id = 1
    }
    {
      name = "OpPhone"
      id = 2
    }
    {
      name = "Fax"
      id = 3
    }
  ]
}
```

What I need is to convert the entry `channels` into a dataframe, is that possible? I was trying with the following code:

```
val ch = confParam.getConfigList("param.channels")
case class Provider(id: String, name: String)
val l = ch.map(conf => Provider(conf.getString("id"), conf.getString("name"))).toList
val df = l.toDF()
```

but I get the error:

> "Error: (28, 20) value toDF is not a member of List [Provider] val df = list.toDF ()"

Comment: see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51042048/parsing-scala-json-into-dataframe/51046795#51046795

Answer (score 0):

To use `toDF()` in Scala you need to import `spark.implicits` in your code. `spark` here refers to to a `SparkSession` object, for example in Spark 2.0+:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
```

Then do the import:

```
import spark.implicits._
```

This will allow you to use functions such as `toDF`, `toDS`, etc.